# Create pointers array from unknown type array in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, types

I need to write a function the takes:

an unknown type array, size of the array and size of the elements

and return an array of pointers: first the negative value and then the positive values. this is what Iv done so far:

```
void *mix(void *A, int nElementsA, int sizeOfAnElement) {
    char** res = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*nElementsA*sizeOfAnElement);
    char* p = (char *)A;
    char* bStart = res[0];
    char* bEnd = res[nElementsA*sizeOfAnElement - sizeOfAnElement];
    while (p<(char*)A + nElementsA*sizeOfAnElement) {
        if (*(int*)p>0) {
            bStart = p;
            bStart += sizeOfAnElement;
        }
        else {
            bEnd = p;
            bEnd -= sizeOfAnElement;
        }
        p += sizeOfAnElement;
    }
    return res;
}
```

and i get array full of rubbish,
what Iv dove wrong?

Comment: Can you make an [mcve] to show how you use/call the function?

Comment: How do you want to interpret and process something *that you don't know what it is*? You can't even know it has "negative elements". What you are currently doing is you *interpret everything as `int`*. You could just as well pass in an `int` array.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: What you are trying to do is impossible and makes little sense.

You say that you have: `an unknown type array` Therefore you can **not** access any elements of the array. Doing:

```
(*(int*)p
```

means that you assume the elements to be of type `int` (or compatible). This obviously conflict with the type being unknown.

Besides that....

This line

```
malloc(sizeof(char*)*nElementsA*sizeOfAnElement);
```

allocates too much memory. It shall only allocate a pointer for each element, i.e.

```
malloc(sizeof(char*)*nElementsA);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

```
void *mix(void *A, int nElementsA, int sizeOfAnElement,
           int (*isPositive)(const void *)) {
    // Allocate a `char*` array containing `nElementsA` pointers.
    char **res = malloc(nElementsA * sizeof *res);

    // &p[i] == &A[i]
    char (*p)[sizeOfAnElement] = A;

    // bStart points to the first result element.
    char **bStart = &res[0];

    // bEnd points to the last result element.
    char **bEnd = &res[nElementsA - 1];

    // Loop through the array,
    // adding &A[i] at the start of the result array if positive,
    // else at the end of the result array.
    for (int i = 0; i < nElementsA; i++) {
        if (isPositive(p[i])) {
            *bStart = p[i];
            bStart++;
        }
        else {
            *bEnd = p[i];
            bEnd--;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Your understanding of what needed to be allocated and how to use your pointers was wrong.

If you want to create an array of pointers, then you need only allocate `nElementsA` pointers, not `nElementsA * sizeOfAnElement` pointers (you're storing pointers, not copies of the objects to which they point).

Then you created and used `bStart` and `bEnd` incorrectly.  If you want to move through an array of `int` objects, then you need an `int*` object.  In the case of `bStart` and `bEnd`, you want to move through an array of `char*`, so you need a `char**`.

I added a function pointer parameter, so you can work with types other than `int` (else what's the point of using `void *A` and `sizeOfAnElement` instead of `int *A`?)  If you need help with that, there are plenty of answers here and tutorials for you to find via search engine.

I also took the liberty of changing `p` to a pointer to an array, so the compiler can perform the pointer arithmetic for you rather than you doing it yourself. You can change it back if you like.  If you want to use pointers in the loop (i.e. you can't use `i`), here's a version of the loop that does that:

```
// I added the typedef for more easily understood declarations of `p` and `end`.
typedef char array_alias_t[sizeOfAnElement];

// p's type is the same as in the previous code (char (*)[sizeOfAnElement]).
array_alias_t *p = A;

// p + x == &p[x], and &p[nElementsA] is one element past the end of A,
// which is allowed by ISO C, provided you don't dereference the pointer
// (i.e. *end is not allowed).
for (array_alias_t *end = p + nElementsA; p != end; p++) {
    if (isPositive(*p)) {
        *bStart = *p;
        bStart++;
    } else {
        *bEnd = *p;
        bEnd--;
    }
}
```